# react datepicker detect month change?

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

Is there a built in prop that can detect when someone changes the month within the navigation?

I need to highlight some specific dates and want to do that calculation when a user decides to change months.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you just have to provide handler to `onMonthChange` prop.

```
<DatePicker
    onMonthChange={console.log}
/>
```